# Does Eclipse create automatic classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is possible in Eclipse after created interface request Eclipse automatically generate implementation class stub? Because now I have to do many operations for it. But all operations are trivial!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your class

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
.........................................................
}
```

Press *Cntrl+1* Select "**Add unimplemented methods**"

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. But create your class, write `implements MyInterface` and then choose "add unimplemented methods" from the red icon on the left.